# Constraint a map type to have certain elements in Scala 3

Tags: scala

In scala 3 I can do

```
val a : 2 = 2 // works
```

But how can I make the following work?

```
val b : Map(1 -> 2) = Map(1 -> 2) // end of statement expected but '(' found
```

My goal is to a make a general class

```
class Task(val settings : Map(String -> Number)) {
    def handleSettings() = {
        for ((k,v) <- settings) {
            // Do something here.
            // I like how this is type safe (in contrast to then
            // if settings was a case class then v would be Any)
        }
    }
}
```

And then extend it

```
// pseudo code
class SpecificTask(val settings : Map("quality" -> Number)) extends Task(settings) {
    def doOwnThing() = {
        settings("quality")
    }
}

val task = SpecificTask(Map("quality" -> 1))
task.handleSettings()
```

I have tried case classes but if I iterate over its elements, the values are implicitly Any. Also it's hard to map case classes to other case classes.

Comment: What is the point of a `Map` that will have only one entry? Just use a tuple.

Comment: Why not `Map[X, Y]`? `X` can be `String` or the literal type `"quality"`.

Comment: @GaëlJ Because I want to add eventually more settings items

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez In this example there's only one but there will be more in practice

Comment: @stacker225 so then what would be the point of this? Or you where expecting for something like `Map("foo" -> 3, "bar" -> 5)`? No, that doesn't exists.

Comment: @stacker225, maybe give us another example of what you'd like to achieve with multiple values then. In my understanding you want to allow only maps with a specific size and specific keys? Maybe Map is not the proper representation of the data you need.

Comment: What about union types, e.g. `val x: Map[1 | 2, 2 | 3] = Map(1 -> 2, 2 -> 3)`?

Comment: Also: why isn't `val x: Map[1, 2] = Map(1 -> 2)` what you need?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez the point is that I would have a data structure similar to Case class but I can iterate it type safely

Comment: @GaëlJ Yes, Every SpecificTask takes a configuration object, which here is a map, because it is easily iterateable and type safe. Is there a good alternative to maps that gives me these benefits?

Comment: @AlinGabrielArhip `class Task(val settings: Map[String, Number])` is good but `class SpecificTask(val settings: Map[String, Number])` is not in my case because I want to force any caller to provide "quality" setting and many other settings.

Comment: @MartinHH that is into the right direction, but unfortunately it cannot guarantee a map to have certain properties

Comment: Maybe a use case for Structural Type: https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/changed-features/structural-types.html?

Comment: Or maybe you want to use proper case classes and a typeclass approach.

Comment: @GaëlJ The structural type looks promising! Thanks

Comment: @stacker225 not even having such map you would be able to iterate it in a type safe manner, using an `HList` of tuples is the closest to what you want but that still won't allow you to iterate it in a type safe manner.

Comment: Unfortunately looks like asInstanceOf doesn't typesafety during compiletime

Comment: Maybe you want something like MapK? https://dev.to/raquo/existential-crisis-implementing-mapk-in-scala-3-2fo1